# Create UserControl in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I develop a web application using ASP.NET MVC4 in VS2012, in that a `HomeController` as `Views/Home/Index.aspx`.

I created a user control as `UC/UC_Menu.ascx` in Views Folder.

In Index.aspx page, I coded in below and run ok.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/UC/UC_Menu.ascx"); %>
```

Now, I want to `UC/UC_Menu.ascx` load data in database. How could I do?

Comment: You should be using Partial View instead.

Comment: He is using aspx engine

Comment: You can create a action method to load data from database and in return of that method just pass this `partialview`.

Comment: @Ajay2707: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing to save the reviewers time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET MVC, views and partials are not supposed to be retrieving any data. They are designed for displaying data that has been retrieved by the corresponding controller under the form of a view model.

So basically you should create a view model that will be a projection of your data. For example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action fetch the data from the database and project it to the view model:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = ... go fetch from db
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and now your `Index.aspx` view will be strongly typed to this view model and pass the model to your partial view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyNs.MyViewModel>" %>
```

and then pass the model to the partial for displaying:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/UC/UC_Menu.ascx", Model); %>
```

and your partial can now display the data:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyNs.MyViewModel>" %>

<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo) %>
<%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Bar) %>
```

Comment: I mean is: load data in user control not load data in view. U can help me.?

Comment: I updated my example to show how to pass the model to the strongly typed partial. And in case you haven't read my answer, I will repeat it once again: in ASP.NET MVC views and partials are not supposed for loading data from anywhere. Their sole purpose is to display data that has been passed to them under the form of a view model. It's a different design pattern compared with classic ASP.NET WebForms where view controls might be fetching data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking "Child Actions" gives you encapsulation similar to "UserControls".

Note: "UserControls" is a term used in ASP.NET Web Forms. In MVC, you would call it a "PartialView".

You could create a child action on your controller, for example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Menu()
    {
       var model = BuildModelFromDB();

       return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Then invoke it in your view, passing in the ActionName and ControllerName:

```
<%= Html.Action("Menu", "Home") %>
```

Comment: thanks.! if i want to use it in master page, how could i do.?

Comment: You should be able to pass in the ActionName and ControllerName like: `<%= Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") %>`

Comment: in controller, i write (return PartialView(model);) or (return PartialView("name_of_partialview",model);)

Comment: Place your view in a views folder that has the same name as your controller. Rename your partialview to the same name of the Action, then return PartialView(model);